# Sorting a data view webpart SharePoint 2007

Tags: data-view-web-part

I am pulling an RSS feed from a blog. I want to be able to list Archives by just listing the titles except I want to sort so that it doesn't display the last published item. Is there a way to exclude this using filtering/sorting from SharePoint Designer? The RSS feed has a specific field for publication date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a Data View Web Part and you sort by Publication Date (descending), then you can add a condition for position() > 1.  That will mean that every item except the first one will be displayed.

Comment: Awesome! This worked like a charm. Thanks for this!